# Q&A in Power BI embedded analytics - We weren't able to load suggestions right now. Please try again later

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are using Q&A in Power BI embedded to show Q&A in a web application.
Same report uploaded to the different Power BI Worspaces and in different Azure AD tenants.

In one tenant with Q&A enabled Q&A working as expected.
In other tenant with Q&A enabled Q&A does not works and it is error message shown:

"We weren't able to load suggestions right now. Please try again later".

No further diagnostic information available at the browser dev tools.

Any suggestion why same report Q&A acts differently in a different Azure AD tenants?

Comment: To make it working need to Enable Preview feature - Q&A for live connected Analysis Services databases

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the report / dashboard and dataset and re-uploading to Power BI. I had renamed a value in my dataset and it was showing this error.